# How to fix error: 'Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in __'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

I set up this spreadsheet to take attendance over Zoom each Am with my students. Students fill out a Google Form to check in. Their data goes into a connected spreadsheet, which in turn goes into a sheet displaying student attendance.
**Prior to any student data being entered**, the cells in rows 3-6 have an error message:

> Error: Query completed with an empty output.

Then when a student name populates one of these cells, the following message appears:

> Error: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G3.

**What I want to happen is for a student name to be displayed (complete with conditional formatting).**

Here's a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpERPaq8yIwDKHkp4T463D6GL5WHAVwHAVYqGmHNJxQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of your query should be corrected.

Please use queries using the following pattern:

```
=query(FormResponses2!D2:G, "select D Where D is not null and D contains 'Anh'")
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: The above formula will solve your issues. Still. Your whole sheet can be highly improved. Please share it with editing privileges -right now it has "View Only"- so I can show you how. If and when you do so, please leave a comment for me here.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this, marikamitsos. My attendance form/sheet works a charm now!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Ashwaq. Glad my answer help you as well :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the the I discovered with this #REF error is that if you are looking up by date and have duplicate values of the same date you are looking for in the lookup data, then you will encounter the same error.